# Polymer - special chars around data bindings

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

When I'm trying to use some "special" characters around the Polymer data bindings it does work, but the linter doesn't recognise the syntax. For example, if I use the starter kit to render the sample `polymer-2-element`, and after that instead of the default:

```
<h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
```

I add

```
<h2>Hello [[[prop1]]]!</h2>
<h2>Hello &#91;[[prop1]]&#93;!</h2>
```

it does work and shows something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qflv9.png

But my problem is that I have `polymer lint` in my build script and it fails because it returns these errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbRWi.png

**LE**: forgot to mention: if I add a space in between the first opening bracket and the data binding it does work.

I realise this is not a very serious problem, but I would like to know if anyone else found a solution to it, because I have had some other problems with HTML entities in Polymer that I had to work around and I'm curious if there's some fix I'm not aware of.

**UPDATE**: also forgot to mention that I am perfectly aware that I can wrap the property in a method call and have it return the padded value, but I was hoping for something simpler to write and easier to understand for anyone reading that code after a while.

Comment: Asked the same question in Polymer Slack earlier today :)